# MirrorMaker 2 stops transfer messages after setting up Schema Registry Transfer SMT. Unknown magic byte

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Trying to set up schema transfer SMT (https://github.com/OneCricketeer/schema-registry-transfer-smt) with MM2.
The first iteration works successfully. A schema is created in the target registry and the messages in the topic are displayed correctly.
But then replication stops, new messages stop coming to the target cluster.
After disabling SMT schema transfer, message replication starts working again, but as expected without SMT, the consumer tries to deserialize events with the source schema ID without success.

We are on Kafka 2.8/Confluent 6.0 and using MM2 for A->B one-way replication.

MirrorMaker 2 settings
**/etc/kafka/connect-mirror-maker.properties:**

```
clusters=source, target-stage
source.bootstrap.servers=broker-src.net:9091
target-stage.bootstrap.servers=broker-target:9091
source->target-stage.enabled=True
source->target-stage.topics=test-mm-.*
topics.blacklist=.*[\\-\\.]internal, .*\\.replica, __.*
target-stage->source.enabled=False
replication.policy.class=com.amazonaws.kafka.samples.CustomMM2ReplicationPolicy
replication.factor=1
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
source->target-stage.transforms=avroSchemaTransfer
source->target-stage.transforms.avroSchemaTransfer.transfer.message.keys=false
source->target-stage.transforms.avroSchemaTransfer.src.schema.registry.url=http://schema-reg-src.net:8081
source->target-stage.transforms.avroSchemaTransfer.src.basic.auth.credentials.source=USER_INFO
source->target-stage.transforms.avroSchemaTransfer.src.basic.auth.user.info=user:pass
source->target-stage.transforms.avroSchemaTransfer.dest.schema.registry.url=http://schema-reg-target.net:8081
source->target-stage.transforms.avroSchemaTransfer.dest.basic.auth.credentials.source=USER_INFO
source->target-stage.transforms.avroSchemaTransfer.dest.basic.auth.user.info=user:pass
source->target-stage.transforms.avroSchemaTransfer.type=cricket.jmoore.kafka.connect.transforms.SchemaRegistryTransfer
```

The logs show these errors:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
```

```
Caused by: cricket.jmoore.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema 1 not found; error code: 40403
```

I can’t figure out what to do with the **magic byte** and who needed **Schema 1**?

MirrorMaker 2 logs slice
**/var/log/kafka/connect-mirror-maker.log:**

```
[2022-12-29 15:50:17,618] INFO Initializing: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain{cricket.jmoore.kafka.connect.transforms.SchemaRegistryTransfer} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:606)

[2022-12-29 15:50:18,365] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorSourceConnector-0} Source task finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:233)
[2022-12-29 15:50:18,438] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-null-12, groupId=null] Cluster ID: tIsZUjsuRvm3HYsWU0lUsA (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata:279)
[2022-12-29 15:50:18,536] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorSourceConnector-1} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:488)
[2022-12-29 15:50:18,536] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorSourceConnector-1} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2022-12-29 15:50:18,537] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorSourceConnector-1} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:191)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:256)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:239)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!


[2022-12-29 15:50:18,601] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorSourceConnector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:191)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:256)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:239)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!

[2022-12-29 15:50:18,602] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorSourceConnector-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:192)
[2022-12-29 15:50:18,604] INFO [Producer clientId=producer-9] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1189)
[2022-12-29 15:50:18,608] INFO Stopping task-thread-MirrorSourceConnector-0 took 6 ms. (org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceTask:120)
[2022-12-29 15:50:18,608] INFO [Producer clientId=target-stage-producer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1189)
[2022-12-29 15:50:22,701] ERROR Unable to fetch schema id 1 in source registry for record value (cricket.jmoore.kafka.connect.transforms.SchemaRegistryTransfer:159)
[2022-12-29 15:50:22,701] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:488)
[2022-12-29 15:50:22,706] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2022-12-29 15:50:22,706] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:191)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:256)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:239)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!

[2022-12-29 15:50:18,602] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorSourceConnector-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:192)
[2022-12-29 15:50:18,604] INFO [Producer clientId=producer-9] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1189)
[2022-12-29 15:50:18,608] INFO Stopping task-thread-MirrorSourceConnector-0 took 6 ms. (org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceTask:120)
[2022-12-29 15:50:18,608] INFO [Producer clientId=target-stage-producer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1189)
[2022-12-29 15:50:22,701] ERROR Unable to fetch schema id 1 in source registry for record value (cricket.jmoore.kafka.connect.transforms.SchemaRegistryTransfer:159)
[2022-12-29 15:50:22,701] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:488)
[2022-12-29 15:50:22,706] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2022-12-29 15:50:22,706] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:191)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:256)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:239)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: cricket.jmoore.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema 1 not found; error code: 40403
    at cricket.jmoore.kafka.connect.transforms.SchemaRegistryTransfer.translateRegistrySchema(SchemaRegistryTransfer.java:163)
    at cricket.jmoore.kafka.connect.transforms.SchemaRegistryTransfer.updateKeyValue(SchemaRegistryTransfer.java:113)
    at cricket.jmoore.kafka.connect.transforms.SchemaRegistryTransfer.apply(SchemaRegistryTransfer.java:72)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: cricket.jmoore.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema 1 not found; error code: 40403
    at cricket.jmoore.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:292)
    at cricket.jmoore.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:352)
    at cricket.jmoore.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:660)
    at cricket.jmoore.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:642)
    at cricket.jmoore.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:225)
    at cricket.jmoore.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:299)
    at cricket.jmoore.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaById(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:284)
    at cricket.jmoore.kafka.connect.transforms.SchemaRegistryTransfer.translateRegistrySchema(SchemaRegistryTransfer.java:157)
    ... 16 more
[2022-12-29 15:50:22,706] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:192)

[2022-12-29 15:50:22,707] INFO [Producer clientId=target-stage-producer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1189)
[2022-12-29 15:51:06,669] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:488)
[2022-12-29 15:51:06,670] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2022-12-29 15:51:06,705] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorCheckpointConnector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:488)
[2022-12-29 15:51:06,705] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorCheckpointConnector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2022-12-29 15:51:06,711] INFO Stopping task-thread-MirrorCheckpointConnector-0 took 6 ms. (org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointTask:98)
[2022-12-29 15:51:06,711] INFO [Producer clientId=target-stage-producer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1189)
[2022-12-29 15:51:06,784] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} Finished commitOffsets successfully in 115 ms (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:586)
[2022-12-29 15:51:12,501] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:488)
[2022-12-29 15:51:12,502] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2022-12-29 15:51:17,691] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorSourceConnector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:488)
[2022-12-29 15:51:17,691] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorSourceConnector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2022-12-29 15:51:17,713] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorCheckpointConnector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:488)
[2022-12-29 15:51:17,714] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorCheckpointConnector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)

[2022-12-29 17:00:07,890] INFO Found 0 new topic-partitions on source. Found 0 deleted topic-partitions on source. Found 97 topic-partitions missing on target-stage.
(org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector:241)

[2022-12-29 17:10:07,976] INFO Found 0 new topic-partitions on source. Found 0 deleted topic-partitions on source. Found 97 topic-partitions missing on target-stage.
(org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector:241)

[2022-12-29 17:16:07,140] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:488)
[2022-12-29 17:16:07,140] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2022-12-29 17:16:07,142] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} Finished commitOffsets successfully in 2 ms (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:586)
[2022-12-29 17:16:12,556] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:488)
[2022-12-29 17:16:12,556] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorHeartbeatConnector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2022-12-29 17:16:17,831] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorSourceConnector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:488)
[2022-12-29 17:16:17,832] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorSourceConnector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2022-12-29 17:16:17,833] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorCheckpointConnector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:488)
[2022-12-29 17:16:17,833] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorCheckpointConnector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2022-12-29 17:16:17,833] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorSourceConnector-1} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:488)
[2022-12-29 17:16:17,833] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorSourceConnector-1} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for using my SMT.

The unknown byte error will occur if someone doesn't send a valid payload into your topic.

The schema not found error can only happen on the `source registry`, as the error says, since it's copying from there.

> After disabling the SMT schema transfer, message replication starts working again

Okay, but can you **deserialize** those events with a consumer successfully?

Comment: The unknown magic byte error appears only when the SMT is enabled.

Comment: I'm replicating several topics and none of them use Schema 1. Perhaps this schema is needed for some internal topic.

Comment: Updated my original post:  
*After disabling the SMT schema transfer, message replication starts working again but consumer unsuccessfully try deserialize events with source schema id.*

Comment: Sounds like you misunderstood my answer. There's a producer somewhere that's sending data into your topic that doesn't use the Schema Registry. Therefore, the bytes of the data payload either 1) Start with the magic byte, but have the next four bytes of a integer 1 (whether valid schema or not, is irrelevant since the data isn't actually serialized to the Registry) 2) data doesn't start with magic byte... Those are the two main failure scenarios for the SMT. You could also reproduce the error writing a consumer in your source Kafka cluster

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks for the clarification. In one of my topics, the data came without a schema. Removed this topic from the mm2 replication list and the **magic byte error** went away.

Comment: Parameter `transforms.avroSchemaTransfer.avro.topics=mytopic:false` is mentioned in the adjacent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61742209/smt-does-not-work-when-added-to-connect-mirror-maker-properties-mirrormaker-2). Is this setting working? How to use it?

Comment: The colon is simply part of the topic name. It doesn't control anything